# parquet vs cassandra size on disk

Tags: python, apache-spark, cassandra, parquet, spark-cassandra-connector

i wrote a data frame to cassandra whose size on linux in parquet format is 7.8G and its size on cassandra is 21.3G what could be the reason for size increase in cassandra.

**size on parquet 7.8G**

**SIZE on cassandra 21.3G**

how is this realted to compaction ratio in cassandra

Comment: how do you measure the disk usage in cassandra? If the data is on a cluster it is replicated typically on 3 nodes so you should expect it to take 3 times as much disk space as parquet.

Comment: it was a different issue there was data loss